# Synergy & SQLyog compatibility issue

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, synergy

I am using `Synergy` and `SQLyog` from many years but they have become incompatible.

I cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> in SQLyog Edtitor, instead of cutting, it inserts a special char `CAN`

You can see the bug here

[image]

I use the latest version of both software (*1.7.6 for Synergy and v12.2.2 64bit for SQLyog Ultimate*) and running Windows 7.

Synergy is in server mode, I have two clients (*a Windows 10 and Mac OSX 10.10.5*)

Have you experienced a similar issue, is there a workaround?

Comment: FWIW, "CAN" is ASCII character 24, "Cancel", which is invoked in a terminal with, you guessed it, Ctrl+X. So this makes sense, but this is still of course an issue

Comment: with further experience I can tell that the problem do not happens immediatly, if I shut down the synergy server (sqlyog is running on the same PC), the problem stop for a while.

Comment: Have you tried updating? Synergy 1.7 is very old now.

Comment: I'm sorry I changed of employer and I no longer use synergy, so I don't know if the problem is fixed in newer versions, do you think I should delete this question?